# How to make a head call using Spring 5 WebClient

Tags: spring, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I am not able to make a HEAD call to a rest service using WebClient.
I want to just read the count header as need to use the same in further rest calls, how can the same be achieved how can I convert the Mono> to the integer count value.
The GET call is successfull however the HEAD call always fails, I am using the following code :

```
private void getResultCount(WebClient webClient)
{

     Mono<ClientResponse> response = webClient.head()
        .uri("/rest/v2/electronics/products/search/?query=::category:575:")
        .exchange()
        .doOnSuccess(clientResponse -> System.out.println("clientResponse.headers() = " + clientResponse.headers()));


     System.out.println("response "+response);
}
```

Comment: Which kind of error do you get?

Comment: Please elaborate on "the HEAD call always fails"; are you getting an exception?

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you were asking is how you extract information from the Head call, when its response is in the HEADERS and not in the body, I needed something similar and after a while I found this [baeldung article](https://www.baeldung.com/java-string-from-mono)

My solution was:

```
var aHeader = aClient.head()
        .retrieve()
        .toEntity(String.class)
        .map(aResponse -> aResponse.getHeaders())
        .block();
System.out.println(aHeader);
```